# Ubuntu 16.04 Nvidia geforce gt 610 display and sound by hdmi

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, graphics, hdmi

I just did a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04 on my machine, which has a nvidia gefore gt610 graphics card.After the ubuntu installation the display is working nicely, but I had no sound (by hdmi). The device was listed in the sound config tool and selected, but although I can change the volume, there is no sound.

So after some reading on the web I decided to install a nvidia driver. So after some playing around I did

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo apt-get install nvidia-370
reboot
```

And suddently I had a visual and my sound was finally working. (I first install 304 and 340, but those didn't work correctly). When I booted today again my display stopped working. During booting it hangs saying something like nvidia persistence stopping.

So I removed and rebooted, I had again visual but no sound. But installing the 370 driver again results in the same result.

I'm not sure what to do next. I can ssh to the machine, so I can do all the commands I want to ..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to install the nvidia 340 driver. The standard driver doesn't support sound. Other drivers of nvdia don't work well with my graphics card

Answer (score 0):

Go to your sound menu and make sure that HDMI is selected. I also had this problem. By default the system is set up to play on an internal sound system.

Comment: As state above, already did that. I first thought that as well so I checked that, but that didnt fix it :(

Comment: You know, installing several drivers version without removing/purging the last ones tends to have that effect: Lots of issues.